# I want to show my window when the keyboard shortcut - show desktop has invoked,is there any function can get this?

Tags: cocoa

I want to show my window when the keyboard shortcut - show desktop has invoked,is there any function can get this?

I display this window under a custom status bar item. So I want to do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solve this by myself,I think maybe you need this sometime,just set window `self.window.collectionBehavior = NSWindowCollectionBehaviorStationary;` 
window will display all the time.